# Minimum possible value of Bob's house number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

The house numbers of Alice, Bob, and Charlie are formed with the same digits: $abc$, $bc$, $c$. If the sum of these numbers equals 912, what is the minimum possible value of $b$?

Comment: $a=9$ and $c=4$? With $b=0$?

Comment: What are the possible values of $c$? Given that, what are the possible values of $b$? Given that, what are the possible values of $a$?

Comment: @QC_QAOA Perhaps $b=0$ is illegal since $bc$ wouldn't really make sense in this case. OP should clarify this. Otherwise, I agree.

Comment: QC_QAOA, that doesn't work for me, because then Bob's house number would be a single-digit number.

Comment: @Henry, I would think that would be a pretty long list. Also, I'm hoping to solve the problem with methods other than brute force.

Comment: @MathPassenger In this case, since you found a solution with $b=5$, we must check what happens if $b \leq 4$. If $b \leq 4$, then this forces $a=9$, and thus it fails since $20b > 12$. So $b=5$ is indeed the minimum value.

Comment: @MathPassenger it is a short list and, if Bob does not live with Charlie, a very short list

Comment: That's very helpful @Evariste. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my work and the helpful comment of @Evariste, I will proceed to write down a solution.

From the problem,
\begin{align*}
(10^2a + 10^1b + 10^0c) + (10^1b + 10^0c) + 10^0c &= 912\\
(100a + 10b + c) + (10b + c) + c &= 900 + 10 + 2\\
100a + 20b + 3c &= 800 + 100 + 12
\end{align*}
One solution of the above is $a = 8$, $b = 5$, and $c = 4$, and therefore a value of $b$ satisfying the problem is $b = 5$. We now show that this is indeed the minimum. If $b \leq 4$, then we must have $a = 9$, which fails because $20b > 12$. Therefore, the minimum value of $b$ is $5$.